# Weird errors on Gradient Descent in Octave (Syntax errors on known command)

Tags: octave, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement Gradient descent in octave. I know I can do it by calculating every value of theta by itself like this

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters

theta_0 = theta(1) - alpha / m * sum(X * theta - y);
theta_1 = theta(2) - alpha / m * sum((X * theta - y) .* X(:, 2));

theta = [theta_0; theta_1];

% Save the cost J in every iteration    
J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

But I want to implement it with vectors in one step like this:

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters

theta = theta - (alpha/m * sum(((X * theta) - y).*X)

 % Save the cost J in every iteration 
J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

The problem is when I run the second piece of code I get this error:

```
syntax error

>>> J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
            ^
```

What have I done wrong / how can I fix this?

Comment: Look at the line *before* the one identified in the error. You've got unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Thanks but now I get this comment error:                                            gradientDescent: operator -: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x1, op2 is 97x2)
error: called from
    gradientDescent at line 19 column 8                                                                                            The line it is refering to is the line containing the J_hisory function @beaker

Comment: That would be an entirely different question, but I would suggest trying to debug the problem before posting. The error says that the problem is in `operator -`, which doesn't appear in the line you mention. It also says that you're trying to subtract a `97x2` array from a `2x1` array. Is that possible? What are the dimensions of the operands in your code? What do you expect them to be? If you narrow the problem down and answer these questions, and you still have problems, we would need a [mre] including sample values for the variables.